# Buoyancy with Object of Heterogeneous Density

Tags: fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

The Archimedes buoyancy principle usually seems to be taken for objects of homogeneous density.  So for example a sphere would have mass equal to $(4/3) \pi r^3 \rho$, where $\rho$ is the density.  Let's say we have a sphere and decide how far it submerges by balancing the weight with the buoyancy

How would this change if the bottom half of the sphere had a slightly lower density than the top half, with the lower density part going first into the water?  Does one have a sum of two different weights for each part, but how is it encoded that the low density part goes first into the water?

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “encoded.” One can consider arbitrarily small uniform regions when evaluating the buoyancy.

Comment: Isn't the density in the buoyancy force the density of fluid, not the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree to which an object will be submerged but float will depend on the average density of the object, not on the distribution of the density. The difference between an object of uniform density and one of non uniform density, but where both have the same average density, will be the orientation of the floating object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I think I came to the same conclusion since writing this, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

The buoyancy phenomenon is essentially equivalent to putting the object on one side of a scale and the same volume of water on the other (that's how Archimedes effectively used it in fact). Whichever side is heavier will go down, the other up. This is obviously both independent of the internal structure of the object and also its shape. Only its total weight in comparison to the total weight of the same volume of water (i.e. only its average density) matters. The only thing that an odd density distribution would do is making the orientation of the object unstable. So it would rotate into a position that minimizes the torque on the object.